# DocumentEvents.Update.Before Kentico Global Event Handler runs more than once

Tags: c#, kentico

I have assigned a handler to **DocumentEvents.Update.Before** event. It triggers once a document is updated but the issue is that it triggers 6 times! I was wondering why it happens more than once and how I can prevent it!

Answer (score 1):

This topic has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399387/can-i-change-a-value-of-a-property-in-a-treenode-in-a-documentevents-update-befo/54406000#54406000)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I have read that article before and was looking for a sample of using Recursion Control or e.DetectRecursion as prefer using it than RequestStockHelper.